# Problems with image types for template matching using OpenCV

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, winapi, visual-c++

I'm using `OpenCV` in `C++` to perform template matching between a screenshot and an image from the disk. My screenshot seems to have the type `CV_8UC4` but my template image has the type `CV_8UC3`. This causes the `matchTemplate` function to get an assertion error:

```
OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\...\opencv4\src\4.3.0-0c6047baf6.clean\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

To tackle this problem I tried to convert both `cv::Mat`s to the same type using the `convertTo` function:

```
screen_shot.convertTo(screen_shot, CV_8UC3);
template_image.convertTo(template_image, CV_8UC3);
```

Surprisingly this does "nothing". The types of both `cv::Mat`s are unmodified after the call. Why?

Another try was modifying the screenshot creation code to produce type `CV_8UC3` directly. However, this then makes the `GetDIBits()` function fail:

```
bool dump_window_screen_to_opencv_mat(const HWND window_handle, cv::Mat& output_mat)
{
    auto* const h_window_dc = GetDC(window_handle);
    auto* const h_window_compatible_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(h_window_dc);
    if (!h_window_compatible_dc)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!SetStretchBltMode(h_window_compatible_dc, COLORONCOLOR))
    {
        DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);
        return false;
    }

    const auto window_resolution = // ...
    const auto loc_window_width = window_resolution.x;
    const auto loc_window_height = window_resolution.y;

    const auto h_bit_map = CreateCompatibleBitmap(h_window_dc, loc_window_width, loc_window_height);
    if (!h_bit_map)
    {
        DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);
        return false;
    }

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bit_map_info_header;
    bit_map_info_header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bit_map_info_header.biWidth = loc_window_width;
    bit_map_info_header.biHeight = -loc_window_height;
    bit_map_info_header.biPlanes = 1;
    bit_map_info_header.biBitCount = 32;
    bit_map_info_header.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bit_map_info_header.biSizeImage = 0;
    bit_map_info_header.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bit_map_info_header.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bit_map_info_header.biClrUsed = 0;
    bit_map_info_header.biClrImportant = 0;

    if (!SelectObject(h_window_compatible_dc, h_bit_map))
    {
        DeleteObject(h_bit_map);
        DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);
        return false;
    }

    if (!StretchBlt(
        h_window_compatible_dc,
        0, 0,
        loc_window_width, loc_window_height,
        h_window_dc,
        0, 0,
        loc_window_width, loc_window_height,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        DeleteObject(h_bit_map);
        DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);
        return false;
    }

    output_mat.create(loc_window_height, loc_window_width, CV_8UC4); // <-- Here we can specify the image type

    const auto has_di_bits_succeeded = GetDIBits(
        h_window_dc,
        h_bit_map,
        0,
        loc_window_height,
        output_mat.data,
        reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO*>(&bit_map_info_header),
        DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    if (!has_di_bits_succeeded)
    {
        DeleteObject(h_bit_map);
        DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);
        return false;
    }

    DeleteObject(h_bit_map);
    DeleteDC(h_window_compatible_dc);

    return true;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this code to produce the correct image type or maybe I can try something completely different?

Check out this related question on `opencv.org`:
https://answers.opencv.org/question/236225

Answer (score 0):

In [cv::Mat::convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b) specs in the description of `rtype` (the second parameter) it is stated that it is the

> desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth **since the number of channels are the same as the input has**; if rtype is negative, the output matrix will have the same type as the input.

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but couldn't find any other explanation.

Try using [cv::cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) with an appropriate [color code](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html), in your case one of `cv::COLOR_xxxA2xxx`, most probably `cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR` (or `cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB`, doesn't matter since they're equal and only the alpha channel is removed). Or the other way around if you want to add alpha channel to the other image, which suits you best. I mostly use it to change an image to grayscale like so:

```
cv::Mat img_gray, image = imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
cv::cvtColor(image, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```